# is it possible to retrieve the time when the current run started?

Tags: time, timestamp, azure-logic-apps

**How do we retrieve the datetime when the logic app started execution?**

In our logic apps, we are currently setting a variable just to capture the datetime of when the workflow started executing, like so:

[image]

**How do get the time when the logic app started execution without having to declare a variable at the beginning to capture `utcNow()`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now no directly action or function to get the startTime property, however you could use Rest API in runtime with Correlation ID to get it. This is the api description :[Workflow Runs - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowruns/get).

The Resource Group name and the workflow name are static and the Correlation ID is dynamic you could use `workflow()['run']['name']` to get it. And then use `body('HTTP')['properties']['startTime']` to get time from response.

The below is my flow.

[image]

[image]

And this is the result, cause the timezone so thy are 8 hours apart.

[image]

Hope this could help you.

Comment: you dont need a separate HTTP request to get that stuff, you can simply set the variable to  `workflow().run.name`

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''', you don't see my answer careful.'workflow().run.name  is used t oget the Correlation ID, and the HTTP action is to call the REST api to response the workflow runs detail, the detail json data contains the start date.

Comment: And if this could help you, please accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

An easier option (which to be honest may have been added to Azure Logic Apps) since @George Chen's answer in 2019) is to use the `trigger()` expression to obtain the JSON object that contains information about what triggered the Logic App run. The desired value is in the `startTime` property of this object. Below is an example of what the `trigger()` expression returns as a JSON object for my Logic App, which is triggered by an HTTP call. This should be similar for a message queue trigger:

```json
{
  "name": "manual",
  "inputs": {
    "schema": {
      "properties": {
        "requestGUID": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "requestGUID"
      ],
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "outputs": {
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Host": "***.logic.azure.com",
      "User-Agent": "curl/7.79.1",
      "Content-Length": "54",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
      "requestGUID": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  },
  "startTime": "2022-02-22T02:14:47.5168196Z",
  "endTime": "2022-02-22T02:14:47.5168196Z",
  "trackingId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "clientTrackingId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "originHistoryName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "status": "Succeeded"
}
```

Based on this object and which referencing notation you prefer, you could get the Logic App start date & time (UTC) using the formula `@trigger().startTime` or `@trigger()?['startTime']`.

Comment: Example (w/ Epoch time): `div(sub(ticks(trigger().startTime),621355968000000000),10000000)`